# GCC compiler wrong optimization

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-optimization

this piece of code not executed properly with GCC -O2 compiler optimization. O2 optimization just cause memory leak  of Foo objects. this works fine with -O3 or without any optimization.can you please explain why this is not working with -O2.
issue introduced with gcc version 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3) (GCC).please note that compiler is 64bit and application also 64bit.

```
#include<stdlib.h>


class Foo
{
public:
        Foo()
        {
                p_UserData = NULL;
        }
        void* p_UserData;
};

void Destroy(Foo* pFoo)
{
        long* pL = (long*)&pFoo->p_UserData;
        if(--(*pL) <= 0)
                delete pFoo;
}

int main()
{
        int i = 0;
        while( i < 10)
        {
                Foo* pFoo = new Foo();
                long* pL = (long*)&pFoo->p_UserData;
                *pL = 1;
                Destroy(pFoo);
                i++;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code has several instances of undefined behaviour - you should be fixing your code, not blaming the compiler.

Comment: `long* pL = (long*)&pFoo->p_UserData;` should be `long* pL = (long*)(pFoo->p_UserData);`

Comment: @sgar91 that would be undefined just as well (not that particular line, but stuff that's going on later).

Comment: @jrok.. sorry my mistake, I didn't see that memory is not being allocated anywhere and the pointer is still `NULL`.

Comment: i here to learn something from it. can someone please explain more clearly ,other than saying undefined behavior.

Comment: @nsa: Declaring a variable of one type (like `void*`) and then accessing it through a pointer or reference to a different type (like `long`) gives undefined behaviour. If you do that, the program could do anything. I can't guess exactly what your compiler is doing, since I don't have access to that version of GCC and my version doesn't behave like that. Possibly, `void*` and `long` have different sizes; possibly, it's optimising the code as if one or more of the dodgy writes had no effect; possibly, something else. You'd need to check the disassembly to see exactly what it's doing.

Comment: @nsa: you should probably explain what the code is supposed to do when it eventually works properly - at present it does nothing other than corrupt memory.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Isn't aliasing through `void*` explicitly allowed?

Comment: @jrok: Yes, but that's not happening here. It's reinterpreting `void**` (**not** `void*`) as `long*`.

Comment: we are not touching any memory location that is pointed from p_UserData. we just change the p_UserData variable through long pointer.

Comment: @Paul R - i'm not corrupt any memory in this program. if you check code properly program not accessing memory location pointed by p_UserData.

Comment: @nsa: I suspect you're corrupting memory (or at least getting undefined behaviour of some sort) because you're breaking aliasing rules when you illegally cast a `void *` to a `long` and this may well result in bad code generation. This is not the compiler's fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a version of your code which doesn't break aliasing rules:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() : userData(0L) { }

    long userData;
};

void Destroy(Foo* pFoo)
{
    if (--pFoo->userData <= 0)
    {
        delete pFoo;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 10)
    {
        Foo* pFoo = new Foo();
        pFoo->userData = 1;
        Destroy(pFoo);
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You might want to rename `userData` to something more meaningful, e.g. `refCount`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is happening at -O2 optimization level, but I can see at least following issues in your code:

1. Memory is not allocated for `pFoo->p_UserData`
2. I don't think that it's a good idea use the `void*` if you use it after as `long*`
3. In `Destroy()` `pL` actually is a `void**` as you are taking the address of `pFoo->p_UserData` that is `void*`, so you are trying to change a pointer inside the `Foo` object.

Comment: 1. true, but initialized. 2.wrong. we using void** as long* 3.yes that's correct. we changing the value of the pointer. but not the content pointed by p_UserData

Comment: @nsa: no, you're using a `void *` as a `long` - this breaks strict aliasing rules.

Comment: @PaulR i can accept your answer .but can you show us best practices that we can solve this problem. please do not add your answer as a comment.

Comment: Sure - but you still haven't explained what it is that you are actually trying to *achieve* - if you do that then I and others can probably give you some good answers, but all we have at the moment is some broken code with no background or explanation of your intent.

Comment: @PaulR - assume pFoo is a shared object.so we need to destroy this object after the using it. so p_UserData used as a reference counter.we create the pFoo object and increment the ref counter per consumer and last consumer will destroy the Object.